# Free Tool to Generate Diagram of SQLite Database

Tags: database, diagrams, sqlite

I tried using openoffice via ODBC, and it connected properly, but when I tried to use tools->Relationships... , it gave me the error message "The database does not support relations."

I'm using OOo 2.4, on Debian 5, if that makes any difference.

I'm not set on using OpenOffice, anything that can generate a diagram with relationships will do fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584149/which-tools-are-available-to-reverse-engineer-a-sqlite-database